# How to change jest.mock value for different tests when mocked class is a dependency on on the SUT?

Tags: jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I am testing a class `DogService.ts`. But `DogService` has a private dependency called `CatService` that gets `new`'ed up in the constructor. I can successfully mock the dependency using:

```
jest.mock('../CatService', () => {
    return {
        CatService: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                someFunction: (async (someArg) => {
                    return await someAsyncMethod();
                })
            }
        })
    }
});
```

And it gets injected fine in the test:

```
describe("", () => {
    it("", async () => {
        const dogService = new DogService();
        ...
    });
});
```

There's no import for the `CatService` in my jest test file. The mock I guess is the import. However, I want to swap out the implementation of `CatService` in different tests. I have tried `jest.resetModules()` and a bunch of other things. Further, the above only seems to work when the mock is outside any tests. If I move it into the describe() function the real `CatService` is used.

Any ideas how to do this? Most tutorials are for mocking classes or functions you directly use in the jest test, but obviously I am mocking a dependency.

Comment: Do CatService.mockImplementation every time you need to change the implementation (or better mockImplementationOnce to not reset default implementation). The point of Jest spies is that they can change implementation multiple times.

Comment: Doesn't work. I tested this yesterday so my memory is vague, but I basically wrote the tests in a linear fashion changing the mock between tests. Don't remember if the real service was used, or if the mock just wasn't updated. My situation is unique in that I am not actually using the mocked class in the test file. Its a dependency on the class being tested. I had no success in trying to spy on it with jest.spy either. It's a private field on the parent service.

Comment: There's nothing unique, it's a common scenario. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and actual error for your attempt, so a fix could be suggested.

Comment: There is no error. The mock either stays the same as whatever was hoisted first or sometimes it calls the real method. My workaround is just editing the prototype but I would rather not. All evidence suggests this is a unique scenario since I cannot find a solution nor has anyone answered. So maybe my design is just wrong, it's more like Java I suppose. But when testing in Java, specifically using DI, mockito can handle this stuff for you. In typescript/jest doesn't seem so much.

Comment: There's no common problem in Jest associated with described case, so it means that you did something wrong. See the comment about MCVE. It's necessary for code-related questions. If you're able to reproduce the problem in independent environment like https://repl.it/languages/jest , this would be more helpful.

Comment: I disagree. I don't believe what I am trying to do specifically is possible. A class I am testing gets instantiated in each one of my tests. That class has another class attached to it as a private member. I want to mock that private class multiple times in my test file, specifically in separate describe() blocks. When I have time I will try to update the question and/or reproduce, but I think that's pretty clear the objective. Documentation doesn't provide a solution at all. There are no examples anywhere. No one has answered (yet). So, its likely that people just make the dependency public.